# Why additional excel window appears

Tags: excel, vba

**Scenario**

I am using a macro whereby I use `Application.Visible = False` to hide the workbooks. Also I use `Application.Visible = True` to unhide the workbook. At certain situation, I use `Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False` and `Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True` to hide and unhide only the workbook which contains macro.

**Problem**

I noticed during these operations, some additional excel windows(without any workbook) appear other than the workbook. Please see the picture below. You can see a grey window behind with a name `Excel`. That is the window I am talking about

[image]

If I closed that window, the whole excel will close. Does anyone know why this extra window appearing and how to prevent it from appearing?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will meet the needs of your specific situation. But, what if you kept `Application.Visible = False` at the beginning of your code and changed `Application.Visible = True` to 
`Application.Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True` at the end. This worked for me.

Comment: I am trying this method, but in my situation, its not working. I will check further

Answer (score 0):

## Hiding Excel

With the following code

```
Sub AppVisibleTrue
  Application.Visible = True
End Sub
Sub AppVisibleFalse
  Application.Visible = False
End Sub
```

you are showing or 'hiding' the 'whole' excel application, so you have to 'unhide' it in the same code, otherwise you won't be able to use the open files after you hide it, e.g. open a new workbook, in VBE add a new module and paste the above code into the module. Now, **stay** in VBE!!! Run the '**False**' Sub. You will notice Excel has 'vanished', but you can still find it in the Task Manager's processes. Now run the '**True**' Sub. Excel has 'reappeared'.

The following process will make Excel 'vanish'. The only way to close it will be via the Task Manager. If you not too familiar with doing this, just take my word for it.
Close the VBE. Now run the 'False' Sub. Excel has 'vanished'.

To conclude, this is obviously an error in your code, so I would suggest if you want to show a window (worksheet) that isn't 'ThisWorkbook' and you're dancing from one to the other, you should declare a variable

```
Const strSheet as String = "Sheet2"
Dim oSheet as Worksheet
'...
Set oSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheet)
```

Now you do with `oSheet` whatever you want.

Try to lose **Active**, **Select** and similar methods in the code.

If you would provide the actual scenario with the codes, a better assessment of the problem could be done.

Comment: I want to hide the application for seeing it more complete like a software instead of  seeing excel in the background.

Comment: That's a reason enough. Well, I still think you should upload the whole codes so someone could recreate the scenario on his/her computer and investigate further.

Comment: Well that is a whole lot of codes calling so many subroutines and modules. Its hard to paste all those codes here. But I am sure some people already encountered this issue before. So I am hoping some light from them

Answer (score 0):

The additional Excel window(s) could be related to your Windows Explorer. If you are previewing a document (in this case an Excel document) then the application to view that document is running in the background.

In this case, forcing the application to be visible will also make the background "preview" windows visible.

Comment: Do you know how to hide those windows then?

Comment: @Anu: I have always closed manually because I didn't work with hidden applications often. And when I came across this, I had made the application visible to check on a bug (endless loop) in code that I was running hidden. Not sure how to fix it programmatically.